# How to create a strong halo light effect?

Tags: light, effects

How to achieve the strong light effect (you may see in some games and 3d renders), where the light is so strong it's penetrating the objects? 
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the compositor Glare node with the type set to 'Fog Glow'.

Ensure you have a suitable emission material behind the 'windows' to ensure there is a bright area for the glow to act on. Add a 'Glow' node and set the type to 'Fog Glow'.

Adjust the parameters of the Fog Glow and/or change the intensity of the emitter to get the desired effect.

[image]

No glow, a moderate glow, a strong glow :

[image]

Comment: The important parameter to understand is the **Threshold** value. Scene Referred Values below the set threshold will not be affected by the glare node. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54168/any-way-to-control-light-halos-in-the-compositor-based-on-emission-level/54173#54173