# Green lantern like construct material in Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, compositing-nodes, transparency

How do I create a Green lantern like construct material  in Blender.
Hear are some reference images.

[image]
[image: Green Lantern fist construct]

This is my attempt but It's not exactly what I'm looking for. For one think I'll like a a bit of a glow.

[image: Green Lantern gun [![My attempt]

If you can help please let me know.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/how-to-render-a-mesh-transparent-with-a-color-on-its-edges-only-with-nodes/28423#28423

Comment: For the glow use a glow node in the compositor: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65727/how-to-create-a-strong-halo-light-effect/65728#65728

Comment: Yeah for a glow you'll need to use the compositor.