# Changing HDRI exposure within Blender

Tags: light, hdri

I've been looking for some HDRs to use in an animation, and I realize that they're going to be exceptionally expensive.

This is why I'm wondering if I can change the exposure of an HDR from within Blender to get everything I can out of one HDR. The purpose of an HDR is to have a High Dynamic Range. This means I should be able to scale the exposure of the HDR and still have varying depths of light.

Here's a comparison between a jpeg(left) and an HDR(right) as an example of how HDRs have broader depths of light when the exposure is changed:

[image: JPG exposure vs HDR exposure]
<sup>(Source: [How to make your own HDRI](http://adaptivesamples.com/2016/03/16/make-your-own-hdri/))</sup>

Of course, this should already make sense if you're familiar with HDRs.

So I want to be able to use an HDR at multiple exposures. **Is there any way I can change the exposure in Blender?** I know there are some other programs that do that, but Blender should be able to do it.

Right now, I use the background node's "Strength" parameter to change the brightness, but that doesn't make the lighting of the objects in the scene darker or lighter respectively.

Comment: Using the strength value is the way to control the exposure. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO2nq.gif Please add more information on what you are doing.

Comment: Can you post an image of your current world settings and your node tree for world?

Comment: Maybe you have some other lamps contributing to the scene, which aren't affected by changing the strength of the background shader (a separate light source).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the answer of troy_s in this question here [How to measure the dynamic range of an HDRi?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66503/how-to-measure-the-dynamic-range-of-an-hdri/66896?noredirect=1#comment116204_66896), he states in the first paragraph that:

> An F-Stop is a halving and doubling of light, relative to the exposure
>   referenced.

Now from my own trial and error testing in Blender, that's exactly what happens when you change the exposure value in Blenders color management settings:

[image: exposure settings]

If we now apply this thinking as a formula, for each color pixel this would mean to do the following for each color channel:

```
Pixel(x) = x * math.pow(exposure_value, 2)
```

Transferred into nodes, this could look like the following Node setup:

[image: node setup]

In a world node tree, you would now have something as easy as this if you transfer it into a node group:

[image: node group]

You can find this node group, and also a similar one for the compositor to doodle around, in this Blend:

[image]

Comment: Why is there a ^2 before the multiply node? An F-stop isn't just multiplying exposure by 2?

Comment: @Mareck the way I understand it, each FStop change is a multiplication by two. So it means, increase one stop, it's A * 2. increase two stops, it's A * 2 * 2, so 2 to the power of 2, increasing by three stops is A * 2 * 2 * 2,...

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you've done. The value you enter in your node setup is the number of stops not really the exposure itself, am I right?

Comment: @Mareck that's correct. I named it 'exposure' as the Blender UI uses this term a lot.