# Python: Check image brightness

Tags: python, image, color

I want to do a test for image brightness in the rendered image (`bpy.data.images["Render Result"]`). I would like to be able to see if the image is dark or light. An example output of the code could be `The rendered image is: light`

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66503/how-to-measure-the-dynamic-range-of-an-hdri

Comment: In relation to what?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the pixel data directly through the `Image.pixels` property. It is a list of repeated RGBA values. To access a single pixel, use this:

```
img = bpy.data.images["Render Result"]
value = img.pixels[(y * img.width + x) * 4 + channel]
```

where `channel` is `0` for red, `1` for green, `2` for blue and `3` for transparency.

Now, image brightness is not a clearly defined thing. You can, for example, calculate the average pixel value over the whole image:

```
r, g, b = [sum(img.pixels[:][i::4]) / len(img.pixels) for i in range(3)]
```

That was "average" as in "arithmetic mean". Another possible interpretation of image brightness is a quantile, say, the 95th:

```
import numpy as np
r, g, b = [np.quantile(img.pixels[:][i::4], 0.95) for i in range(3)]
```

The specific choice probably depends on the kind of images you are processing.

Comment: This just gives me 1.0 every time.

Comment: The maximum value is often 1, and it means that at least one pixel of the whole is bright. If you want a more specific measure of brightness, be more specific in your question.

Comment: So how to I calculate image brightness from this?