# Is there a Cycles equivalent to Eevee's Bloom Option?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light, shaders, eevee-render-engine

Is there any equivalent option or process to get results equal, similar or better than Eevee's Bloom? If yes, how could I do it? I have an object with Emission Surface on Material in that case it is representing a sun, and the results I need are exactly or a little better than what Eevee's bloom is giving, but, Eevee's mesh render doesn't look as good as Cycles so I was wondering if there was such a thing. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54168/any-way-to-control-light-halos-in-the-compositor-based-on-emission-level/54173#54173 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender/15680#15680

Comment: Thanks Bro, I will check it out!

Answer (score 5):

Use the Glare node in compositing, or design your own via a threshold and blurs. Use appropriate alpha encoding and handling and you'll be well on your way without much effort. 99% of the battle is knowledge on the latter aspect of alpha.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2djfEly About Glare Node, I'm using Blender 2.8 and I can't find it during compositing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't crop your images so tight, showing the interface is useful. Make sure you are in the compositor and not the material node editor.

Comment: alright so, first off, thanks for the advice, *I was in fact looking in the wrong place, Glare node is located in compositor not in material node editor*, so thank you, I didn't respond because I ended up letting it go because I had another thing going on, but here I am again. I tried using it but I think i'm doing something wrong, look the way I set up and it still not working the way I want, what should I do? https://imgur.com/DBDndfJ

Comment: Any option to have glare in viewport so modifier values are seen in real time ?

Comment: Glare node still valid in 3.1: [Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/glare.html) and [use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-bzr6L7ueM).