# How can I add Emission to the "Mortar" of a grid texture?

Tags: emission

I'm new at Blender, and so far I’ve made a simple grid:

[image]

That is how my grid looks right now, but I want the green part to emit light, I knew that emission would work well, but the input for that is a color, not a material.

Does anyone know how to make this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want this to emit the material instead of just a basic color? Also, are you wanting glow for your emission?

Comment: I want the green part (the grid), to glow, I am aiming for a glowing si-fi look so, hope you understand. -tysm AncientBison

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you generate your grid texture with a Brick Texture node, you can connect the Fac output to the Emission Strength input of a Principled BSDF:

[image]

Note the green glow cast on the small sphere.

If you want a more visible glow/glare around the grid itself, you could try adding some volumetric mist, or you could fake it with Bloom (in Eevee) or [using a Glare node in compositing (in Cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140151/is-there-a-cycles-equivalent-to-eevees-bloom-option). Here’s an example using Bloom:

[image]

(Note that to get the indirect lighting on the sphere to work in Eevee you will need to add Light Probes and bake the lights.)

Comment: Cool, the emission strength is finally there :). Blender 2.92?

Comment: @JachymMichal It was added in 2.91. :)