# How do I render with cycles with the same bloom effects as Eevee?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I want to render an animation in cycles it has a lot of bloom for the neon effects and most of the bloom is just gone in cycles.

Comment: 2 ways I can think of are to 1) use a volume (fog) to show the bloom, or 2) Do it in the compositor (try glare node).

Comment: to add to Christopher's comment, you could also try this trick in the following video (it's in french but rather easy to understand, it's about the Layer Weight node): https://youtu.be/6uMAJayajWE

Comment: woooow. who made this AMAAAAAAZING video?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Cycles equivalent to Eevee's Bloom Option?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140151/is-there-a-cycles-equivalent-to-eevees-bloom-option)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender/15680#15680

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the glare node to get the same effect, along with some adjustments if you want to modify the strength or give the bloom a uniform color.
[image: EEVEE Bloom effect][image: Cycles Bloom effect][image: Compositor nodes]

You can also use the "greater than" math node to extract the bright parts of an image, blur them, and add them back together. The result however isn't as pretty as the method above.