# is there a way i can control which parts of the render have the glow?

Tags: compositing-nodes

im trying to replicate something similar to below where near the exhaust the flames are extremely bright and towards the end of the flame it fades out. i got the glow to be amped up but i have no idea how i can go about controlling where the glow is coming from.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the threshold value.

Pixels that are brighter than the threshold will get the glow.

Values lower than those set by the threshold will not be affected.

Read: [Any way to control light halos in the compositor based on emission level?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54168/any-way-to-control-light-halos-in-the-compositor-based-on-emission-level/54173#54173)