# Glare Node not act as Expected

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, emission

Do not understand why Only 1 part of my Emission Tube glow via Glare node in Compositing Tab.
Thanks in advance.
[image: Mix = -1]
[image: Mix = 1]

Comment: You might need to crank up the brightness on the blue light tube or else lowering the threshold on the glare node.  As for the dot on the bottom of the green tube, I would probably have to see the blender file to find out what's causing that.  You can upload blender files here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=xME66Lvq" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/xME66Lvq/)

Answer (score 3):

The glare node works based on a threshold value. Meaning only the pixels that have values larger than the set value will be affected by glare/bloom/glow.

Use a lower value until you get what you need.

Also, keep the mix at $0$. If you set it to $-1$ you are actually cancelling the effect completely.

> **Mix**
>
> Value to control how much of the effect is added on to the image. A value of -1 would give just the original image, $0$ gives a $50/50$ mix, and $1$ gives just the effect.
>
> **Threshold**
>
> Pixels brighter than this value will be affected by the glare filter.

(Form the [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/glare.html))

Read [Control light halos in the compositor based on emission level](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/54173/92768)