# Compositor: Uncontrollable glare and noise artifacts

Tags: compositing-nodes

In the compositor, I often have an uncontrollable glare I don't know how to get rid of. Usually, tweaking the threshold fixes the problem, but not with those noisy artifacts. Here is my basic setting:
[image: Compositing node settings]

And here is my artifacts:

[image: Artifact 01]
[image: Artifact 02]

I have noticed that the material provoking this is often (maybe always?) some kind of metal. How do you use metal and glare without have this kind of glitch?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're using a multiply node, which can get crazy.  Remember light values can go far above 1.

Comment: It helps if you understand how the threshold control works.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54168/any-way-to-control-light-halos-in-the-compositor-based-on-emission-level/54173#54173. As for the noise, it is hard to tell without more information. It looks like could be artifacts caused by the denoiser,or some kind of incompatibility in the GPU. Please [edit] your post and add more information and a link to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I spent this morning investigating (another time) this issue and finally found out!

To make glass more interesting I need base color > 1, with some color. I know this is not physically correct, but it looks nice. However it also produces this artifact.

A lot of time wasted on this... but now I know. Thanks Allen and susu for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this on a file I was setting up involving some sparklers outputting very intense light to also illuminate the scene they were in.

It's something the scene denoiser was causing in combination with the glare node. I specifically was using the default scene denoiser of NLM, haven't played around with other denoisers to see if one is less susceptible to this.

If I sourced the "noisy image" socket and then used the compositor's denoising node *after* the glare (with the appropriate data passes output and hooked up), it fixed the problem.

Hope that helps, especially if anyone else runs into the same thing and stumbles across this article like I did.