# Laser bolt glare problem in blender 2.9

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

So I'm trying to build a laser bolt like in Star Wars, and I added a cylinder with an emission texture. The problem is, in Star Wars, the laser bolts have glare, so I added a glare node in the compositing tab. I rendered the image with the camera, and there was no difference.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the .blend by using this uploader: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LgRwe6jm/, without knowledge of the rest of your setup it is nearly impossible to determine the actual cause (without lots of external knowledge), it basically becomes guesswork

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Glow with depth in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender) read also: [control halos in compositor based on emission levels](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54168/any-way-to-control-light-halos-in-the-compositor-based-on-emission-level/54173#54173)

Comment: try changing stroke dropdown to fog from glare node of simply mix original image with a blured one

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a higher value then 0 in you Mix Slider from the Glare, or the Glare wont mix in your Picture. This will make you Picture a little bit darker but the glare will be visible, you can counter the darkness with the Threshold Value.